# Flutter radar chart add borders

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, charts, path

I'm using this flutter [radar chart](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_radar_chart) library code. I want Mercedes like 3-pointed star, but I don't know how to generate it using low level widgets like [path](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) in flutter. I find this library "radar chart" which for some extent produces the desired result. But my main concern is how can I add or remove borders from bottom side of triangles. As I showed below, I want borders / strokes only on outsides the shapes, not on bottom sides or joints. How can I modify this code to draw this 3-pointed star with outer stroke.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:selfily_flutter_app/presentation/resources/dimension.dart';
import 'package:selfily_flutter_app/presentation/widget/chart_widget/radar_chart/radar_chart.dart';
import 'package:selfily_flutter_app/presentation/widget/sf_spacing.dart';

class MyRadarChart extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyRadarChart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyRadarChartState createState() => _MyRadarChartState();
}

class _MyRadarChartState extends State<MyRadarChart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const ticks = [1, 2, 3];
    var features = ["", '', "", '',"", ''];
    var data = [
      [0, 0.7, 2.5, 0.7],/// Physical , Green Color
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [2.5, 0, -.7, -2.5],/// Mental, Red Color, left side
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [2.5, .7, 0, 0],/// Mental, Red Color, right side
      [0, 0, 0, 0],
      [-.7, -2.5, -.7, 0],/// Social, Blue Color
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          RadarChart(
            axisColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
            outlineColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
            ticks: ticks,
            features: features,
            data: data,
            reverseAxis: true,
            sides: 0,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text("10"),
                HorizontalSpacing(WidthDimension.w_35),
                Text("5"),
                HorizontalSpacing(WidthDimension.w_70),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 3),
                  child: Text("0"),
                ),
                HorizontalSpacing(WidthDimension.w_75),
                Text("5"),
                HorizontalSpacing(WidthDimension.w_35),
                Text("10"),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:math' show atan2, cos, pi, sin;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:selfily_flutter_app/presentation/resources/app_color.dart';

const defaultGraphColors = [
  AppColor.green,
  Colors.white,
  AppColor.primary,
  Colors.white,
  AppColor.primary,
  Colors.white,
  AppColor.pink,
];

class RadarChart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<int> ticks;
  final List<String> features;
  final List<List<num>> data;
  final bool reverseAxis;
  final TextStyle ticksTextStyle;
  final TextStyle featuresTextStyle;
  final Color outlineColor;
  final Color axisColor;
  final List<Color> graphColors;
  final int sides;

  const RadarChart({
    Key? key,
    required this.ticks,
    required this.features,
    required this.data,
    this.reverseAxis = false,
    this.ticksTextStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
    this.featuresTextStyle = const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
    this.outlineColor = Colors.black,
    this.axisColor = Colors.grey,
    this.graphColors = defaultGraphColors,
    this.sides = 0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  factory RadarChart.light({
    required List<int> ticks,
    required List<String> features,
    required List<List<num>> data,
    bool reverseAxis = false,
    bool useSides = false,
  }) {
    return RadarChart(
        ticks: ticks,
        features: features,
        data: data,
        sides: useSides ? features.length : 0);
  }

  factory RadarChart.dark({
    required List<int> ticks,
    required List<String> features,
    required List<List<num>> data,
    bool reverseAxis = false,
    bool useSides = false,
  }) {
    return RadarChart(
        ticks: ticks,
        features: features,
        data: data,
        featuresTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
        outlineColor: Colors.white,
        axisColor: Colors.grey,
        sides: useSides ? features.length : 0);
  }

  @override
  _RadarChartState createState() => _RadarChartState();
}

class _RadarChartState extends State<RadarChart>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double fraction = 0;
  late Animation<double> animation;
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      parent: animationController,
    ))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          fraction = animation.value;
        });
      });
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(RadarChart oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    animationController.reset();
    animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      size: const Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
      painter: RadarChartPainter(
          widget.ticks,
          widget.features,
          widget.data,
          widget.reverseAxis,
          widget.ticksTextStyle,
          widget.featuresTextStyle,
          widget.outlineColor,
          widget.axisColor,
          widget.graphColors,
          widget.sides,
          fraction),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class RadarChartPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<int> ticks;
  final List<String> features;
  final List<List<num>> data;
  final bool reverseAxis;
  final TextStyle ticksTextStyle;
  final TextStyle featuresTextStyle;
  final Color outlineColor;
  final Color axisColor;
  final List<Color> graphColors;
  final int sides;
  final double fraction;

  RadarChartPainter(
      this.ticks,
      this.features,
      this.data,
      this.reverseAxis,
      this.ticksTextStyle,
      this.featuresTextStyle,
      this.outlineColor,
      this.axisColor,
      this.graphColors,
      this.sides,
      this.fraction,
      );

  Path variablePath(Size size, double radius, int sides) {
    var path = Path();
    var angle = (math.pi * 2) / sides;

    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    if (sides < 3) {
      // Draw a circle
      path.addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
        radius: radius,
      ));
    } else {
      // Draw a polygon
      Offset startPoint = Offset(radius * cos(-pi / 2), radius * sin(-pi / 2));

      path.moveTo(startPoint.dx + center.dx, startPoint.dy + center.dy);

      for (int i = 1; i <= sides; i++) {
        double x = radius * cos(angle * i - pi / 2) + center.dx;
        double y = radius * sin(angle * i - pi / 2) + center.dy;
        path.lineTo(x, y);
      }
      path.close();
    }
    return path;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final centerX = size.width / 2.0;
    final centerY = size.height / 2.0;
    final centerOffset = Offset(centerX, centerY);
    final radius = math.min(centerX, centerY) * 0.8;
    final scale = radius / ticks.last;

    // Painting the chart outline
    var outlinePaint = Paint()
      ..color = outlineColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..isAntiAlias = true;

    var ticksPaint = Paint()
      ..color = axisColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0
      ..isAntiAlias = true;

    canvas.drawPath(variablePath(size, radius, sides), outlinePaint);

    // Painting the circles and labels for the given ticks (could be auto-generated)

    var tickDistance = radius / (ticks.length);
    var tickLabels = ticks;

    tickLabels.asMap().forEach((index, tick) {
      var tickRadius = radius - tickDistance * (ticks.length - index - 1);
      var tickOffset = Offset(centerX - tickRadius, centerY);

      // TextPainter(
      //   textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      //   text: TextSpan(text: tick.toString(), style: ticksTextStyle),
      //   textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      // )
      //   ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: size.width)
      //   ..paint(canvas, tickOffset);
    });

    var numbers = tickLabels.reversed.toList();
    numbers.asMap().forEach((index, tick) {
      var tickRadius = radius - tickDistance * index;
      var tickOffset = Offset(centerX + tickRadius, centerY);

      canvas.drawPath(variablePath(size, tickRadius, sides), ticksPaint);

      // TextPainter(
      //   textAlign: TextAlign.right,
      //   text: TextSpan(text: tick.toString(), style: ticksTextStyle),
      //   textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      // )
      //   ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: size.width)
      //   ..paint(canvas, tickOffset);
    });

    // Painting the axis for each given feature
    var angle = (2 * pi) / features.length;

    features.asMap().forEach((index, feature) {
      var xAngle = cos(angle * index - pi / 2);
      var yAngle = sin(angle * index - pi / 2);

      var featureOffset =
      Offset(centerX + radius * xAngle, centerY + radius * yAngle);

      canvas.drawLine(centerOffset, featureOffset, ticksPaint);

      var featureLabelFontHeight = featuresTextStyle.fontSize;
      var labelYOffset = yAngle < 0 ? -featureLabelFontHeight! : 0;
      var labelXOffset = xAngle > 0 ? featureOffset.dx : 0.0;

      TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(text: feature, style: featuresTextStyle),
        textAlign: xAngle < 0 ? TextAlign.right : TextAlign.left,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      )
        ..layout(minWidth: featureOffset.dx)
        ..paint(canvas, Offset(labelXOffset, featureOffset.dy + labelYOffset));
    });

    // Painting each graph
    data.asMap().forEach((index, graph) {
      var graphPaint = Paint()
        ..color = graphColors[index % graphColors.length].withOpacity(0.3)
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
        ..isAntiAlias = true;

      var graphOutlinePaint = Paint()
        ..color = graphColors[index % graphColors.length].withOpacity(0.6)
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
        ..strokeWidth = 1.5
        ..isAntiAlias = true;

      var scaledPoint = scale * graph[0] * fraction;
      var path = Path();
      {
        path.moveTo(centerX, centerY - scaledPoint);
      }

      graph.asMap().forEach((index, point) {
        if (index == 0) return;
        var xAngle = cos(angle * index - pi / 2);
        var yAngle = sin(angle * index - pi / 2);
        var scaledPoint = scale * point * fraction;
        {
          path.lineTo(
              centerX + scaledPoint * xAngle, centerY + scaledPoint * yAngle);
        }
      });
      path.close();
      canvas.drawPath(path, graphPaint);
      canvas.drawPath(path, graphOutlinePaint);
    });
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RadarChartPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.fraction != fraction;
  }
}
```

**This is the result I get** -

[image: Current result]

**This is the result I'm expecting** -

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Do you need the graph background, ticks, circles and stuff, or is it only the Mercedez logo you're interested in?

Comment: I want this to be look identical as shown in second image but remove strokes from inside of shapes.

Comment: I don't know if this solution will work or not , try adding shadow to the bottom border of each triangle .